# Unmarshal to struct with slice returns null value instead of empty slice

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, unmarshalling

If I create a "photo" without any tags it is stored in dynamodb as

```
"tags": {
   "NULL": true
},
```

But when I query and unmarshal the record I would expect that it converts this into an empty slice instead I get this:

```
[{"photo_id":"bmpuh3jg","tags":null}]
```

Is it possible to have it convert it into an empty slice instead? e.g.

```
[{"photo_id":"bmpuh3jg","tags":[]}]
```

## **CODE EXAMPLE**

My struct

```golang
type Photo struct {
    Id        string   `json:"photo_id"`
    Tags      []string `json:"tags"`
}
```

Query

```golang
photo := &Photo{}
input := &dynamodb.QueryInput{
    TableName:                 aws.String("local.photos"),
    KeyConditionExpression:    aws.String("photo_id = :photo_id"),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":photo_id": {
            S: aws.String(photo_id),
        },
    },
}
db_result, err := db.Query(input)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
} else if *db_result.Count == int64(0) {
    // No item found
    return nil, err
}

err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalListOfMaps(db_result.Items, photo)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

photoJSON, err := json.Marshal(photo)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

return photoJSON, nil
```

Comment: ah sorry, that was just an instance of the struct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, to achieve a result with an empty slice for Tags (`{"photo_id":"bmpuh3jg","tags":[]}`), you can do it like this:

```
  jsonString := `{"photo_id":"bmpuh3jg","tags":null}`

  photo := &Photo{}
  err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &photo)
  if err != nil {
     fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }

  // Here is a trick. Replace nil with an empty slice.
  if photo.Tags == nil {
    photo.Tags = []string{}
  }
  elemJSON, err := json.Marshal(photo)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err.Error())
  }
  fmt.Println(string(elemJSON)) //{"photo_id":"bmpuh3jg","tags":[]}
```

To understand, why a nil slice encodes as the null JSON, you can check official documentation https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/

> Array and slice values encode as JSON arrays, except that []byte
>   encodes as a base64-encoded string, and a nil slice encodes as the
>   null JSON value.

Check on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/BsxTpBlypV5

Comment: thanks for your answer. This works but I was hoping there is a solution using tags with the struct and json. But after further research it seems that you have to do this custom to achieve what I want :'(